# Key assignments in init file issue

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, menus

I am customizing emacs X11 on a Linux box. By default, `C-x C-s` is bound to `save-buffer`, and `C-x C-s` shows as the keyboard shortcut in the `File`->`Save` menu. If I put into my `.emacs` file the following line:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-s") 'save-buffer)
```

then both `C-x C-s` and `s-s` are bound to `save-buffer`, but `C-x C-s` shows in the menu as the shortcut. If I put into `.emacs`:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-x C-s"))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-s") 'save-buffer)
```

then only `s-s` is bound to save-buffer and it shows in the `File`->`Save` as the keyboard shortcut. Now if I put into my `.emacs` the following lines:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-x C-s"))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-s") 'save-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") 'save-buffer)
```

only `s-s` ends up being bound to `save-buffer` (and it shows in the `File`->`Save` menu as the keyboard shortcut), while `C-x C-s` ends up being unbound - as if the third line was not there. I was not expecting this behaviour. What am I missing?

Comment: Your last paragraph: Are you sure that `C-x C-s` **is not bound** to `save-buffer`? The fact that it does not show in the menu does not mean that it is not bound to the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask Emacs to show a particular key binding, among those that are bound to a given command, next to a menu item for that command, by using symbol property **`:advertised-binding`**.

This tells Emacs to use `s-s` as the advertised key binding, so that when `save-buffer` is used in a menu item the key binding shown next to it is `s-s`:

```el
(put 'save-buffer ':advertised-binding (kbd "s-s"))
```

See the Emacs manual, node [Menu Bar](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Menu-Bar.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is in fact exactly what I was trying to do. However, when I put this line into the emacs init file (including adding the missing ")" at the end of the line), after the line binding s-s to save-file, it seems to have absolutely no effect. In particular, the menu still advertises "C-x C-s" as the advertised binding, although describe-key confirms that both C-x C-s and s-s are bound to save-buffer. I have tried emacs 24.5.1/GTK+ version 3.22.11 and emacs 25.1.1/GTK+ version 3.22.12, and the behaviour is the same in both cases.

Comment: I think it needs to be :advertised-binding rather than 'advertised-binding, that way it seems to work. Thanks again.

Comment: @user52932: Right you are. I corrected it to include the colon prefix. Thx.